# How to set the state of a widget at an index in a listview.builder in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this listview.builder in a stream builder. Inside the listview I have a button and circular progress indicator in a container at every index, now I want to show the circular indicator at that particular index only when the button is pressed.

I have tried to use a boolean to hide and show the indicator. however my problem is when every try to make the indicator visible all of them become visible which is not what I want. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build every list item as a separate widget with its own logic and state, this way you can have a different boolean state property for every item.

Comment: Thanks.
just for anyone later,this  [The widget manages its own state](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/interactive#the-widget-manages-its-own-state) was helpful

Comment: @Norbert do you have some link for this solution? I'm going in circles trying to find a way to check a state, show an icon and update that same icon according a condition

Comment: @FilipeOS I have added an answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Example to demonstrate How to use a widget which manages its own state in a listview builder.

```
class MainClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainClassState createState() => _MainClassState();
}

class _MainClassState extends State<MainClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
           // itemCount: ,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return HoldNewStateOf(
                  descriptions: "Description From List",
                  index: index,
                  name: "Name From List",
                );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class HoldNewStateOf extends StatefulWidget {
final name;
final descriptions;
final index;

HoldNewStateOf({
this.name,
this.descriptions,
this.index,
});
  @override
  _HoldNewStateOfState createState() => _HoldNewStateOfState();
}

class _HoldNewStateOfState extends State<HoldNewStateOf> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Name: ${widget.name}"),
           Text("Description: ${widget.descriptions}"),
            Text("Current Index: ${widget.index}"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So, I MUST have a separated widget for my itemBuilder in order to have a state/icon different according rules for each item? Thank you!