# Flutter riverpod update state of specific index in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have an app that makes a post request to an API with data about drivers and orders. The initial page displays a list of drivers in individual list tiles. The list tile has a drop down option. Clicking on that option brings you to a new page with a list view of orders for that driver. Clicking on an individual order brings you to a form. On submitting and validating this form, I want to change the color of that orders text from red to green. Each Order has a submitted flag, and when it submits I would want to change that to true and then have the color change. When all the orders are green within an List View, I want the color of that driver to turn green. I've been going over riverpod tutorials and documentation but can't quite figure out how to get this done. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DriversPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**drivers.dart - This is where the drivers are displayed**

```
class DriversPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final HttpService httpService = HttpService();
  var colorChoice = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Drivers")
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
        future: httpService.getOrders(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Order>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Order> orders = snapshot.data;
            return ListView(
              children: orders.map((Order order) => Card(child: ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(order.driver, style: TextStyle(color: colorChoice),),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26)
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(title: Text("Orders"),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrdersState(driverName: order.driver, driverOrders: order.orders))),),
                  ),
                ],
              ))).toList(),
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }),
    ));
  }
}
```

**orders.dart - This is where the orders for a driver are displayed. I originally had it as a stateful widget but turned it into a Consumer Widget and took an attempt at making a provider but was lost on how to handle it in a listview like this. As you can see here I am using the ternary operator for the text color based on item.submitted**

```
final driverListProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => new DriverListTest());

class OrdersState extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String driverName;
  final List<OrderElement> driverOrders;

  const OrdersState({Key key, this.driverName, this.driverOrders}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(driverName),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: driverOrders.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            final item = driverOrders[index];
            return Card(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                child: ListTile(title: Text(item.order, style: TextStyle(color: item.submitted? Colors.green : Colors.red),),
                subtitle: Text('${item.company}\n${item.address}'),
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrderForm(orderTitle: item.order,))),));
          }),
      );
  }
}
```

**orderform.dart - Only showing one field for the form, figured the rest was not neccessary, just need to show what happens on submit.**

```
class OrderForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final String orderTitle;

  const OrderForm({this.orderTitle});

  @override
  _OrderFormState createState() => _OrderFormState();
}

class _OrderFormState extends State<OrderForm> {
  @override
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _orderModel = Order();
  List<String> _pickerNames = ['Loader 1', 'Loader 2', 'Loader 3', 'Loader 4'];
  String _selectedPickedBy;
  String _selectedCheckedBy;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,title: Center(
          child: Text(widget.orderTitle),
        ),),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(
              Icons.delete
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    scrollable: true,
                    title: Text('Login'),
                    content: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Form(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Reason',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Reason 1',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Reason 2',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Submit"),
                          onPressed: () {

                          })
                    ],
                  );
            });
          }
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    DropdownButtonFormField(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      hint: Text('Picked By'),
                      value: _selectedPickedBy,
                      onChanged: (newValue){
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedPickedBy = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      validator: (value) => value == null
                          ? 'Picked By Required' : null,
                      items: _pickerNames.map((picker) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: new Text(picker),
                          value: picker,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onSaved: (value) => setState(() => _orderModel.pickedBy = value) ,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0
                      ),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          final form = _formKey.currentState;
                          if (form.validate()){
                            form.save();
                            Navigator.pop(context,);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text("Submit"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        )
    );

  }
}
```

**ordermodel.dart - This is the model for the drivers and orders when making http requests to my api. At the bottom you can see where I attempt at making a statenotifier and what I'm trying to with accepting a list of OrderElement(The list of orders).**

```
List<Order> orderFromJson(String str) => List<Order>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Order.fromJson(x)));

String orderToJson(List<Order> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Order {
  Order({
    this.driver,
    this.orders,
  });

  String driver;
  List<OrderElement> orders;

  factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Order(
    driver: json["Driver"],
    orders: List<OrderElement>.from(json["Orders"].map((x) => OrderElement.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Driver": driver,
    "Orders": List<dynamic>.from(orders.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class OrderElement {
  OrderElement({
    this.order,
    this.company,
    this.address,
    this.submitted,
    this.index,
  });

  String order;
  String company;
  String address;
  bool submitted;
  num index;

  factory OrderElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => OrderElement(
    order: json["Order"],
    company: json["Company"],
    address: json["Address"],
    submitted: json["submitted"],
    index: json["index"]
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Order": order,
    "Company": company,
    "Address": address,
  };
}

class DriverListTest extends StateNotifier<List<OrderElement>> {
  DriverListTest([List<OrderElement> drivers1]) : super(drivers1 ?? []);


  void onSubmit(num index) {
    state = [
      for(final currentOrder in state)
        if (currentOrder.index == index)
          OrderElement(
            order: currentOrder.order,
            company: currentOrder.company,
            address: currentOrder.address,
            submitted: !currentOrder.submitted,
            index: currentOrder.index,
          )
      else
        currentOrder,
    ];
  }
}
```

Don't know if my Http class is necessary but let me know if it is. I tried following https://www.refactord.com/guides/riverpod-state-management-explained and [How to set the state of a widget at an index in a listview.builder in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470676/how-to-set-the-state-of-a-widget-at-an-index-in-a-listview-builder-in-flutter) how to handle individual widgets but again I just got lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.